# Connecting php to oracle database on two different machines

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

Hello I am a newbie in PHP and Oracle and I have to connect PHP to Oracle database on two different machines.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaa.bbb.ccc) 
(PORT=1632))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=int)))";
$conn = oci_connect("aaa", "bbb", $servername);
if (!$conn) {
$m = oci_error();
echo $m['message'], "\n";
exit;
}
else {
print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
 // Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

The error that i get is: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-e\serial.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-efactura\serial.php on line 4**

I have read online that I have to decomment the **extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client** which I did and install Oracle Instant Client 12 32 bit and add it to the path of the environment variables which I did. I even restarted the PC and it still gives me the same error. Do you have any ideea why id doesn`t work ? I am working from XAMPP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: oracle connectivity is an advanced topic, I would recommend to start with another database like mariadb. otherwise, test your oracle client with another tool to ensure that it is working before starting with php

Comment: I am working on a project at work and this is the database

Comment: are you able to use the oracle client with another program?

Comment: if you cmmoent out the oracle extension, ensure that another extension is loaded which provides you the oci_connect()-function

Comment: Read Oracle's blog post about [Installing XAMPP on Windows](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/installing-xampp-on-windows-for-php-and-oracle-database).    Did you install the required VS Redistributable (see the Instant Client download page).